# How do I get a Metro Style app version from a desktop application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I get a installed Metro app version from a desktop application?

Comment: you are going to need to elaborate more on this... I am not sure what you are asking exactly. What is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2012/10/calling-winrt-from-windows-desktop-apps.html

```
var pm = new PackageManager();
IEnumerable<Package> packages = pm.FindPackages();
foreach (var package in packages)
{
    if (package.Id.FullName.Equals("X"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Architecture: {0}", package.Id.Architecture.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Family: {0}", package.Id.FamilyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Full name: {0}", package.Id.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", package.Id.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Publisher: {0}", package.Id.Publisher);
        Console.WriteLine("Publisher Id: {0}", package.Id.PublisherId);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", package.Id.Version.Major, package.Id.Version.Minor, package.Id.Version.Revision, package.Id.Version.Build);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little correction for Vinicius's answer.
Correct order of version numbers is major, minor, build (not revision), revision.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking exactly. But if you search a desktop app in marketplace is possible that is just develeped or you can use and install the desktop app like in windows 7 or windows XP.